# How to declare a connection object on a class level connection not in local scope with VB.NET?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I got the error:

> Fill: SelectCommand.Connection property has not been initialized.

I think this is because I declare my data set not inside the `private sub`  but in the `public class`.....
but I need to use the data set in more than once in different `private sub` during the program....how should I define it ?
many thanks.

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Public Class Form1
Dim con As SqlConnection
Dim strsql As String
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con)
Dim ds As New DataSet()
Dim strcon As String
Dim newmode As Boolean
Dim newrow As DataRow
Dim cb As SqlCommandBuilder

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    newmode = False
    'Dim con As SqlConnection
    'Dim strsql As String
    con = New SqlConnection("initial catalog=test;data source=nazi;integrated security=sspi;")
    strsql = "select*from table_1"
    con.Open()
    'Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con)
    'Dim ds As New DataSet()

    da.Fill(ds, "dd")

    TextBox1.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", ds, "dd.tel"))
    TextBox2.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", ds, "dd.nam"))
    TextBox3.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", ds, "dd.address"))
    da.update(ds, "dd")
    con.Close()
End Sub

Private Sub empty()
    textrecord.text = ""
    TextBox1.text = ""
    TextBox2.text = ""
    TextBox3.text = ""
    TextBox4.text = ""
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    newrow = ds.Tables("dd").NewRow
    newmode = True
    textrecord.BackColor = Color.Red
    textrecord.Text = "new record"
    MsgBox("enter new record and press save")
    Call empty()
End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: i don't know why some part of the code is not illustrated in the code window ?

Comment: The code should be indented by four spaces (or select it, and press CTRL-K)

Comment: A `DataSet` doesn't know of or use the connection used to fill it, once it has been filled - just because you want to share the `DataSet` around (and so keep it as a class field) doesn't mean that the connection object can't be a local variable in the one method where the fill takes place. Also - `Call` - seriously?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You create the DataAdapter at the global level in this line

```
Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con)
```

but at this point in time your strsql is empty and if you change it afterwards it doesn't change inside the dataadatpter, thus the error message.

If you insist on keeping all that global vars (and it's considered a bad practice as @Andomar pointed out in is answer) then you should be sure to create the DataAdapter with the correct sqlstring just before its usage:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load     
    newmode = False     
    con = New SqlConnection("initial catalog=test;data source=nazi;integrated security=sspi;") 
    strsql = "select*from table_1"     
    con.Open()     
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con) '<- added this line here '  
    da.Fill(ds, "dd")      
    ....
    con.Close() 
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
```

try adding `New`:

```
Dim con As New SqlConnection("initial catalog=test;...")
```

However, it's best practice to only open a connection just before you need it, and close it right after.  Connections should be local variables [in `Using` blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), not class variables!

Comment: Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(strsql, con)
         Dim ds As New DataSet()
 
when i declared these two line inside the private sub form_1 , program run without error ...but when it get to the second private sub(button_1) , the error is "what is ds?"  even if i delet the con.close() statement  do i have to declare ds and da again?every time i want to use them? of course not , but what is the solution?